# Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (1): `c' used. } - I am finding this error while runnin the file

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{\textbf{Organizational Association}}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        1  
        *{2}{S[table-format=2.0]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.0]}
    }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{} }       
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Jagatsinghpur}}
    
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Baripada} }  \\
    
    \cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
    & {{BJD}}
    & {{Congress}}
    & {{BJD}}
    & {{BJP}}
    \\              
    \midrule
    \midrule
    1-4 Year&   3.9 &12.7&  16.7&   8.9\\
    5-10 Year   &18.9&  21.1&   42.2&   32.2\\
    11-15 year& 22.8    &24.4   &20 &24.4\\
    16- 20 year&    54.4&   41.8    &21.1&  34.4\\
    
    \midrule
    \midrule
    
\end{tabular*}
\\
{\raggedright \textit{Note: f= Figure in parentheses are in percentage.}  \par}
{\raggedright \textit{ N= 90 From each party .}  \par}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Why, yes: you have for the table preamble: `1 *{2}{S[table-format=2.0] S[table-format=2.2] S[table-format=2.0]}`. I suppose you meant `l`, not 1.

Comment: Apart from the typo, Bernard already pointed out, please also be aware that the `table-format` option of your `S` type columns do not match the contents of the corresponding columns. Using `*{4}{S[table-format=2.1]}` instead of `*{2}{S[table-format=2.0] S[table-format=2.2] S[table-format=2.0]}` would be more appropriate and also helps to get rid of the "overfull box"  warnings.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to fixing an obvious typo -- use `l` ("ell") rather than `1` ("one") as the symbol for a left-aligned column -- and using `S[table-format=2.1]` as the common column type for all four data columns, you may also want to use en-dashes rather than short dashes in the strings in the first column.

A separate comment: You seem be quite fond of using **bold-facing** and *italics* to "decorate" various elements of the table. My advice: Don't overdo it. In fact, do consider removing both types of decoration from the table -- you'll be amazed just how much more streamlined and appealing the table will look.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[textfont=bf,skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{Organizational Association}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{S[table-format=2.1]} }
    \toprule   
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Jagatsinghpur}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{Baripada}}  \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
    & {BJD} & {Congress} & {BJD} & {BJP} \\              
    \midrule
    1--4 year    &  3.9 & 12.7 & 16.7 &  8.9 \\
    5--10 year   & 18.9 & 21.1 & 42.2 & 32.2 \\
    11--15 year  & 22.8 & 24.4 & 20   & 24.4 \\
    16--20 year  & 54.4 & 41.8 & 21.1 & 34.4 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip
\textit{Note: Figures in parentheses are in percentage.} \par
\textit{$N= 90$ from each party.} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```